# Redirect Loop MVC3 Search Form Using HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, http-get

hope someone can help because I've been racking my brains for the best part of yesterday evening!  Basically, I'm trying to get a search form working using HttpGet so I can potentially retrieve results from an external source via the URL like:

http://url.com/Area/Controller/Action/SearchCategory/SearchCriteria

I create and pass a model to my view containing two properties for **SearchCategory** and **SearchCriteria** and have the associated HTML controls in the view.  This works perfectly if I choose both a category AND enter something for my criteria.  However, if I don't enter anything in my criteria I get an infinite redirect.  My route for this particular feature looks like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Dashboard-Search",
    "Area/Controller/Action/{SearchCategory}/{SearchCriteria}",
    new { 
        controller = "Controller", 
        action = "Action", 
        SearchCategory = "", 
        SearchCriteria = "" 
    }
);
```

I do have my model implementing IValidateableObject and validate that something has been entered, but obviously the route binding is done before anything can be validated.

Any ideas???

**Routes**

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Dashboard-Search-NoCriteria",
    "HEP/Dashboard/Search/{category}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Search", category = "Case No" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Dashboard-Search",
    "HEP/Dashboard/Search/{category}/{criteria}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Search", category = "Case No", criteria = "" }
);
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string SearchCategory, string SearchCriteria)
{
    // create new instance of model and add search criteria so entered
    // data persists on post back
    DashboardModel model = new DashboardModel() {
        SearchCategory = SearchCategory,
        SearchCriteria = SearchCriteria
    };
    model.Search(SearchCategory, SearchCriteria);

    // return the HTML view of another controller that displays the same list,
    // only this time, the list is filtered according to GET data
    return View("Overview", model);
}
```

**HTML Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Get)) {

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchCategory, "Category:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchCategory, new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "Category", Value = "Category" }
    })

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchCriteria, "Criteria:")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchCriteria)

    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" />

}
```

Comment: I know I can prevent this by using client side validation to prevent the form being posted without anything in **SearchCriteria** but my concern is what if the user has a script blocker / javascript disabled for some reason.  I think an infinite loop just looks like I'm not doing things right!

Comment: What do you mean by "don't enter anything in my criteria" ? Is Criteria passed as GET parameter or as URL part (your routing code looks like the latter option)? If criteria is passed as part of URL then not specifying it means you have an URL that doesn't match the pattern for your `Dashboard-Search` route and it's getting redirected via some other route. Could you provide more info on how you're passing Criteria (sample URL?) and post your entire `RegisterRoutes` function code?

Comment: There are literally 2 input boxes on a form within a <form method="get">, when submitted (with something in criteria) the key/value pairs are put into the querystring OK.  However, if I don't enter any criteria only the category's key/value pair is appended to the querystring.  What I'm basically after is someway to prevent the routing unless something specifically has been entered into the criteria input.

Comment: If you're using `form method="get"` then what's your `action` here? If it's empty(not specified) then it must be the current URL - the URL your search form is accessible from. Could you post it?

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe I should instead POST the data and in the controller's action and handle presence checking there.  If criteria has been POSTed then RedirectToAction with the correct URL parameters, otherwise return validation errors to the view?

Comment: Isn't it "acceptable" to just use an url like "`http://url.com/Area/Controller/Action?SearchCategory=mvc3&SearchCriteria=routes`"?

Comment: Ron - no, that negates the purpose of a URL rewrite.  I know it may seem pedantic but I want the URLs looking neat and simple.  I've finally managed to achieve what I wanted by POSTing back to the initial controller, validating the data there and then return RedirectToAction to the search controller.  This seems to be working fine.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Install and use [routedebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) which will show you which route has been used for specific URL. quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routes right now do not correspond to your search form.

URL that satisfies your `Dashboard-Search` route should look like

```
http://example.com/HEP/Dashboard/Search/SampleCategory/SampleCriteria
```

Your form in turn will produce a GET request to URL like this:

```
http://example.com/HEP/Dashboard/Search/?Category=SampleCategory&Criteria=SampleCriteria
```

Most probably your method `Search(string SearchCategory, string SearchCriteria)` is not ever called - I'd suggest that your request is redirected back to the method which is just showing your search view without actually performing any search.

Please show the **entire** RegisterRoutes method if you need more explanations or code.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string SearchCategory = null, string SearchCriteria = null)
```

This will allow your controller to work without taking searchcategory or searchcriteria as long as you handle the case in which they are null.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a single route and then setting your defaults differently by making the criteria optional.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Dashboard-Search",
    "HEP/Dashboard/Search/{category}/{criteria}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Search", category = "Case No", criteria = UrlParameter.Optional });
```